# Decoding JSON dump as object

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I am doing my college assignment and one of the things my lecture is looking for is encoding an object and dumping it as JSON, decoding it then loading it into the `PassengerFlight` class.

When I run the code it keeps showing

> 'PassengerFlight' object has no attribute 'airlineName'

When I decode it, VSCode is showing it has all the set function variables.  The only class I can get it to run in is the `Flight` class when I remove the abstract method.  Is there any way to run it within the `PassengerFlight` class and not show the above error?

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
import json
from json import JSONEncoder


class Flight(ABC, object):  # Flight Class (MAIN)
    def __init__(self, airlineName, departureAirport, arrivalAirport):  # Constructor Method
        self.airlineName: str  # Declaring attributes & Setting Types
        self.departureAirport: str  # Declaring attributes & Setting Types
        self.arrivalAirport: str  # Declaring attributes & Setting Types

    def setAirlineName(self, airlineName):  # Mutator Method
        self.airlineName = airlineName

    @abstractmethod  # Marking this methods as abstract method, any concrete subclass will have to implement this method
    def getPrice(self):
        pass

    def setDepartureAirport(self, departureAirport):  # Mutator Method
        self.departureAirport = departureAirport

    def getDepartureAirport(self):  # Accessor Method
        if len(self.departureAirport) > 0:  # Error Checking
            return self.departureAirport
        else:
            return "No departure airport set"

    def setArrivalAirport(self, arrivalAirport):  # Mutator Method
        self.arrivalAirport = arrivalAirport

    def getArrivalAirport(self):  # Accessor Method
        if len(self.arrivalAirport) > 0:  # Error Checking
            return self.arrivalAirport
        else:
            return "No arrival airport set"

    def __eq__(self, otherFlight):
        return (self.airlineName == otherFlight.airlineName)

    def __str__(self):  # Overiding Method
        return "\n==================================================\n++++++++++++++++++ Flight Info ++++++++++++++++++\n==================================================\nAirline Name: " + self.airlineName + "\Departure Airport: " + self.departureAirport + "\nArrival Airport: " + self.arrivalAirport


class PassengerFlight(Flight, object):  # PassengerFlight Class (EXTENDS MAIN)
    def __init__(self, airlineName, departureAirport, arrivalAirport, price, redEye, passengerList, flightType, baggageWeight):  # Constructor Method
        super().__init__(airlineName, departureAirport, arrivalAirport)
        self.passengerList: list  # Declaring attributes & Setting Types
        self.flightType: str  # Declaring attributes & Setting Types
        self.baggageWeight: float  # Declaring attributes & Setting Types
        self.price: float  # Declaring attributes & Setting Types
        self.redEye: bool

    def getAirlineName(self):  # Accessor Method
        if len(self.airlineName) > 0:  # Error Checking
            return self.airlineName
        else:
            return "No airline name set"

    def setRedEye(self, redEye):
        self.redEye = redEye

    def isRedEye(self):
        if self.redEye == True:
            return "Flight is red eye"
        else:
            return "Flight is not a red eye"

    def setPassengerName(self, passengerList):  # Mutator Method
        self.passengerList = passengerList

    def getPassengerName(self):  # Accessor Method
        if len(self.passengerList) > 0:  # Error Checking
            self.passengerList.sort()
            return self.passengerList
        else:
            return "Passenger List Not Set"

    def setFlightType(self, flightType):  # Mutator Method
        self.flightType = flightType

    def getFlightType(self):  # Accessor Method
        if len(self.flightType) > 0:  # Error Checking
            return self.flightType
        else:
            return "No Flight Type Set"

    def setBaggageWeight(self):  # Mutator Method
        baggageWeight = 0
        for i in range(len(self.passengerList)):  # Iterates through passenger list
            baggageWeight += 50.00  # For each passenger in the list add 50KG to baggage variable
        self.baggageWeight = baggageWeight  # Set our attribute equal to the variable

    def getBaggageWeight(self):  # Accessor Method
        if self.baggageWeight == 0:
            return "No Baggage Weight Set"
        else:
            return self.baggageWeight

    def setPrice(self, price):
        self.price = price * len(self.passengerList)

    def getPrice(self):
        if self.price != 0:
            return self.price
        else:
            return "Price is not set"

    def sortedNames(self):
        return sorted(self.passengerList)

    def __str__(self):  # Overiding Method
        return super().__str__() + "\nPassenger Names using sort(): " + str(self.getPassengerName()) + "\nFlight Type: " + self.flightType + "\nBaggage Weight: " + str(self.baggageWeight) + '(KG)\n' + "Money earned for this flight is: " + str(self.getPrice()) + "\nPassenger Names using Sorted(): " + str(self.sortedNames()) + '\n==================================================\n'

class FlightEncoder(JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, o):
        return o.__dict__


##########################################################
#           Calling PassengerFlight Class           #
##########################################################
# Initialize Class & Set to Variable
passenger = PassengerFlight(None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None)
passenger.setAirlineName('Aer Lingus')  # Set mutators & values
passenger.setArrivalAirport('Chicago O\'Hare Intl')  # Set mutators & values
passenger.setDepartureAirport('Dublin')  # Set mutators & values
passenger.setRedEye(True)
passenger.setFlightType('Long Haul')  # Set mutators & values
passenger.setPassengerName(
    ['Andrew Check', 'Graham Whitaker', 'John Eire', 'Vicky Bunsworth', 'Lorna Lopsworth'])  # Set mutators & values
passenger.setBaggageWeight()  # Set mutators & values
passenger.setPrice(200.00)
# uses the overridden _str_ method to print detail of the class
print(passenger)
##########################################################
passengerEncode = json.dumps(passenger, cls=FlightEncoder, indent=4)
passengerDecode = json.loads(passengerEncode)
passengerObj = PassengerFlight(**passengerDecode)
print(passengerObj)
```

Comment: In both `__init__` functions you are only declaring some variable types, you are not initializing attributes, so they are not defined at runtime.  You need, for example: `self.airlineName = airlineName` for all the attributes in your `__init__` functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Hint

```
def __str__(self):  # Overiding Method
    return (
        super().__str__()
        + "\nPassenger Names using sort(): "
        + str(self.getPassengerName())
        + "\nFlight Type: "
        + self.flightType
        + "\nBaggage Weight: "
        + str(self.baggageWeight)
        + "(KG)\n"
        + "Money earned for this flight is: "
        + str(self.getPrice())
        + "\nPassenger Names using Sorted(): "
        + str(self.sortedNames())
        + "\n==================================================\n"
    )
```

You call `super().__str__()`. `self` is an instance of `PassengerFlight` which inherited from `Flight`. `super()` means: "*call a method defined in the parent class next in `__mro__`*". `Flight` doesn't have the attribute.

---

### super

> The `super()` function is used to give access to methods and properties of a parent or sibling class. The `super()` function returns an object that represents the parent class.

### OOP

Using child class attributes in the parent class breaks the "Dependency Inversion Principle" (SOLID).

> In object-oriented design, a dependency inversion principle is a specific form of decoupling software modules. When following this principle, the conventional dependency relationships established from high-level, policy-setting modules to low-level, dependency modules are reversed, thus rendering high-level modules independent of the low-level module implementation details.

> High-level modules should not depend on low-level modules. Both should depend on abstractions (e.g., interfaces).
> Abstractions should not depend on details. Details (concrete implementations) should depend on abstractions.

Your abstraction depends on the higher-level implementation.

### Solution

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractproperty


class Flight(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    @abstractproperty
    def airLineName(self):
        raise NotImplementedError()
```

With the property declared in the abstraction you have to implement it in the child types. Based on this you can use the abstract properties in the abstraction without errors and risks to call not implemented attribute. Also, it satisfies SOLID principles.

Comment: Thanks for answering.  Doesn't even seem to be working if I use it on the Flight Class now shows the same `'Flight' object has no attribute 'airlineName'` error as before.  That's in the __str__ without the super class.

Comment: The problem is the same, and it is showed in the error. `Flight` object has no `airLineName` attribute. Don't call the child class attributes in the parent class or define abstract properties in the parent.

Comment: This is marked as an answer, yet doesn't seem to answer the question.  I commented above, and I'll comment here:
In both `__init__` functions you are only declaring some variable types, you are not initializing attributes, so they are not defined at runtime.  You need, for example: `self.airlineName = airlineName` for all the attributes in your `__init__` functions.